# How can I add some number to string in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem. Script parsing csv to html. But number is read as a string. How can I add "0" to numbers that do not have to decimals. For example:

```
15,45
12,00
14,2
14,54
```

I want to add 0 to all numbers like 4,2

```
15,45
12,00
14,20
14,54
```

Comment: `12,00` is different from `12.00` What do you expect exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Zerofilled value using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```js
 var output = "15,2".split(",").map(function(val){ return val > 100 ? val: (val+"00").slice(0,2);}).join(",");
alert(output);
 var output = "15,100".split(",").map(function(val){ return val > 99 ? val: (val+"00").slice(0,2);}).join(",");
alert(output);
 var output = "15,".split(",").map(function(val){ return val > 100 ? val: (val+"00").slice(0,2);}).join(",");
alert(output);
```

Comment: @fcalderan for `15,15` it outputted me `15,15` what should be the output in this case?

Comment: try with `15`, should output `15.00`

Comment: @fcalderan it will now, please check

Answer (score 2):

In *vanillaJS*

```
var num = "14,2";

/* string to number conversion */
num = +(num.replace(',','.'));

/* set 2 digits after decimal point */
num = num.toFixed(2);

/*
Input   Output
--------------
14,25   14.25
14,2    14.20
14      14.00  */
```

Reduced in a single statement, as suggested in the comments below:

```
(+num.replace(',','.')).toFixed(2);
```

if you have an array of strings you could easily convert them using `Array.map()`

```
var nums = ["14", "14,2", "14,25"];
nums = nums.map(n => (+n.replace(',','.')).toFixed(2)); 

// => ["14.00", "14.20", "14.25"]
```

Comment: This is the most correct and most performant answer. Maybe compete with the one-liners and write it like this: `(+num.replace(',','.')).toFixed(2);` ?

Comment: yes, but for clarity purpose I splitted the code in two readable (and commented) lines, I'm not doing a codegolf competition :)

Answer (score 1):

If you get all strings as posted format in the OP you could use length :

```js
["15,45","12,00","14,2"].forEach(function(v){
    alert(v.split(',')[1].length==1?v+"0":v);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
var arr = ["15,45","12,00","14,2","14,54"];

var newarr = arr.map(function(o){
  var val = o.split(',');
  return val[1].length == 1 ? val.join(',')+"0" : val.join(',');
});

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newarr, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```